# Renaming all files in another folder?

Tags: renaming

I found this code from a post from 2 years ago.
It works great, but is it possible to set a destination for another folder?

This BAT file renames all .jpg files in the current folder. Im wondering if it is possible to input a destination to rename all jpgs in another folder without going to the folder itself. 
.bat file is located: "C:\Users\%currentuser%\Desktop\Sorted Files\New folder\JPG"
I want it to sort the jpg files located: "C:\Users\%currentuser%\Desktop\Sorted Files\New folder\JPG\New folder"

```
set a=1
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b *.jpg') do (
  ren "%%i" "!a!.jpg" 
  set /a a+=1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

WOW ok all i had to do is use 
cd C:\folder path

I cant believe it was that easy LOL